# Game slows down after a while, potential data leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, p5.js

I'm making a javascript game using p5 and p5.play and for some reason after the simulation runs for more than 20 seconds the entire thing really slows down. I think it may be a data leak but am unsure of what is truly harming performance.

Update: After some poking around I found that I was successfully removing the sprites from the plain group however there is some other Object called allSprites that is collecting the sprites no matter what. How I remove said sprites from this object is still unknown.

Update: Came up with way to remove them from object, still did not fix data leak.

```
var players;
var deadly;
var powerUp;
var plain;
var penguinSheet;
var penguinAnimation;
var willLoad;
var harmless;
var score = 0;

function preload(){
  penguinSheet = loadSpriteSheet('./assets/BoxPenguinSprites.png', 64, 64, 3);
  penguinAnimation = loadAnimation(penguinSheet);
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(700, 600);
    // players = new Group();
    // deadly = new Group();
    // powerUp = new Group();
    // harmless = new Group();
    plain = new Group();
    useQuadTree(true);
    player = createSprite(100, 100, 20, 20);
    player.debug = true;
  }

function update(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var c = createSprite(
      random(width), 0,
      random(25, 75), random(10, 30));
    c.addSpeed(random(1,3), 90);
    c.shapeColor = color(random(30, 50), random(180, 220), random(80, 130));
    plain.add(c);
  }
  // for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
  //   var d = createSprite(
  //     random(width), 0,
  //     random(25, 75), random(10, 30));
  //   d.addSpeed(random(1,3), 90);
  //   d.shapeColor = color(random(0, 30), random(150, 160), random(50, 80));
  //   harmless.add(d);
  // }
}

function cleanUp(){
  for (var j = 0; j < plain.length; j++){
    if (plain[j].newPosition.y > height){
      plain.remove(plain[j]);
    }
  }
  // for (j = 0; j< harmless.length; j++){
  //   if (harmless[j].newPosition.y > height){
  //     harmless.remove(harmless[j]);
  //   }
  // }
}

function pixleBuffer(){
  var offsetX = 0;
  var offsetY = 0;
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
    offsetX = -3;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)){
    offsetX = 3;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)){
    offsetY = -3;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)){
    offsetY = 3;
  }
  player.setCollider("rectangle", offsetX , offsetY, 20, 20);
}
//
function draw() {

  if (frameCount == 1 || frameCount % 100 == 0){
    update();
  }
  // player.overlap(harmless);
  // plain.collide(harmless);
  // harmless.collide(plain);
  // harmless.collide(harmless);
  player.collide(plain);
  plain.collide(plain);
  if(keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
    player.position.x -= 3
  }
  if(keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)){
    player.position.x += 3
  }
  if(keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)){
    player.position.y -=3
  }
  if(keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)){
    player.position.y += 3
  }
  pixleBuffer();
  clear();
  cleanUp();
  drawSprites();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `useQuadTree()` function?

Comment: [QuadTree](http://p5play.molleindustria.org/docs/classes/p5.play.html#method-useQuadTree) It is just something that is supposed to speed up collision detection.